# Which latest version of Unity Engine supported xbox 360 platform?

Tags: game-development, development-environment, platform, xbox360

I'd like to try working on a project that involves the Xbox 360 platform, and I need to know which is the latest version of Unity Engine that officially supports development for Xbox 360.

I was looking for some information but I couldn't find anything that would help me figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

unity 5.6 supports xbox 360, although I don't really understand why you would want to develop for a 20 year old console.